# How to implements an interface in a JSON

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, database, typeorm

I go to the DB and get the 'percent_values' of the 'topics' and average them all, and the JSON that returns me is below, with the 'sector_name' and the average value. But if there is no 'percent_value' of a topic then the sector is not returned. I want to return the sector with mean = 0. How can I do this?

They gave me a tip to use an Interface of the topics and a const with the values ​​of the topics already equal to 0, I created it but I don't know how exactly to implement it... How could I be doing this?

**JSONs**

```
// JSON that returns to me
{
  "Sector1": 4,
  "Sector2": 24,
  "Sector3": 2.5,
  "Sector4": 9.5,
  "Sector6": 74,
  "Total": 19
}

// JSON that I want
{
  "Sector1": 4,
  "Sector2": 24,
  "Sector3": 2.5,
  "Sector4": 9.5,
  "Sector5": 0,
  "Sector6": 74,
  "Total": 19
}
```

**interface and cons**

```
export interface ISectorTopics {
    'Sector1': {
        'topic1': number | null,
        'topic2': number | null,
        'topic3': number | null,
        'topic4': number | null,
        'topic5': number | null
    },
    'Sector2': {
        'topic1': number | null,
        'topic2': number | null
    },
    'Sector3': {
        'topic1': number | null,
        'topic2': number | null,
        'topic3': number | null,
        'topic4': number | null
    },
    'Sector4': {
        'topic1': number | null,
        'topic2': number | null,
        'topic3': number | null,
        'topic4': number | null
    },
    'Sector5': {
        'topic1': number | null,
        'topic2': number | null,
        'topic3': number | null
    },
    'Sector6': {
        'topic1': number | null,
        'topic2': number | null,
        'topic3': number | null
    }
};

export const sectorTopicsDefaultValues : ISectorTopics = {
    'Sector1': {
        'topic1': 0,
        'topic2': 0,
        'topic3': 0,
        'topic4': 0,
        'topic5': 0
    },
    'Sector2': {
        'topic1': 0,
        'topic2': 0
    },
    'Sector3': {
        'topic1': 0,
        'topic2': 0,
        'topic3': 0,
        'topic4': 0
    },
    'Sector4': {
        'topic1': 0,
        'topic2': 0,
        'topic3': 0,
        'topic4': 0
    },
    'Sector5': {
        'topic1': 0,
        'topic2': 0,
        'topic3': 0
    },
    'Sector6': {
        'topic1': 0,
        'topic2': 0,
        'topic3': 0
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor(private dataSource: DataSource) {}

  myRepository = this.dataSource.getRepository(data);

  async getAll(year: number, month: number) {
    let datas;
    await this.myRepository
      .find({
        relations: {
          topic: {
            sector: true
          }
        },
        select: {
          month_reference: true,
          year_reference: true,
          percent_data: true,
          topic: {
            topic_name: true,
            sector: {
              sector_name: true
            }
          }
        },
        where: {
          month_reference: month,
          year_reference: year
        }
      })
      .then((response) => datas = response);

      const dataObj = {}
      const sectors = {};

      datas.forEach((data) => {
        if (!sectors[data.topic.sector.sector_name]) {
          sectors[data.topic.sector.sector_name] = [];
        }
        if (data.month_reference == month && data.year_reference == year) {
          let value;

          data.percent_value ? value = data.percent_value : 0;

          sectors[data.topic.sector.sector_name].push({
            topic_name: data.topic.topic_name,
            percent_value: value,
          });
        };
      });

      // Calculate the Total Average data per Sector
      const sectorEntries = Object.entries(sectors); 
      
      sectorEntries.forEach(([sectorName, sectorArray]) => {  
        const sum = (<any>sectorArray).reduce((accumulator, currentdata) => {
          return accumulator + currentdata.percent_values;
        }, 0);
        
        const sectorAverage = sum / (<any>sectorArray).length;
    
        sectorAverage ? dataObj[sectorName] = sectorAverage : dataObj[sectorName] = 0;
      })
      
      // Calculate the Total Average data
      const averageSectordatas = Object.values(dataObj);
      const averageSum = averageSectordatas.reduce((accumulator, currentdata) => {
        return (+<any>accumulator) + (+<any>currentdata);
      }, 0);

      const averageTotal = (+<any>averageSum) / averageSectordatas.length;

      averageTotal ? dataObj["Total"] = +averageTotal.toFixed(2) : dataObj["averageTotal"] = 0;

      return data;
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this line might be a typo: `data.percent_data ? data = data.percent_data : 0;`, it should probably be `data = data.percent_data ? data.percent_data : 0`

Comment: @Livebughelp-www.dialect.so I think it had a lot of "data" and ended up getting a little confusing, I changed the names, see if it's clearer now